# Accessing parent scope from partial in handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

How to access #each parent scope from partial?

Main template:

```
(out of each = {{index}})<br>            {{!-- some index --}}
{{#each someItem}}
(in each, but not on partial = {{../index}}) {{!-- access to index from parent scope --}}
  {{>part}}
{{/each}}
```

Partial:

```
<div class="part">
  (in partial: {{itemName}} - {{../index}})     {{!-- not working !!! --}}
</div>
```

Here is the Fiddle with problem: 
http://jsfiddle.net/0o8jpxjh/

Comment: you can answer your own question, and later accept it.

Comment: yep, I know. I am waiting 2 days limit to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had the same problem, check your handlebars version. I updated handlebars to 2.0 version and just use {{@root.index}}.